# returning by reference vs returning by value in C++

Tags: c++, function, reference

Given the following vector and functions:

```
std::vector<int> param;
std::vector<int>& getparam_1() {
return param;
}

std::vector<int> getparam_2() {
return param;
}
```

I understand that both following expressions will be compiled:

```
std::vector<int> param_copy1 = getparam_1();
std::vector<int> param_copy2 = getparam_2();
```

But what are their differences?

Comment: Pre-c++17, the later might does 2 copies.

Comment: To really see the difference in the result, compile each with optimizations enabled and look at the assembly.  I would not be surprised to find the assembly identical between the two.

Comment: *But what are their differences?* -- Your question is not clear.  What is the difference in what way?  If you want to get at the actual vector `param` and not a copy, then the call to `getparam_1` is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious difference is you can change the global variable if you return by reference.

**EXAMPLE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> param{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
std::vector<int>& getparam_1()
{
    return param;
}

std::vector<int> getparam_2()
{
    return param;
}

int main()
{
    getparam_1().push_back(9);
    for (const auto& i : param)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

This will print "123459".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> param{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
std::vector<int>& getparam_1()
{
    return param;
}

std::vector<int> getparam_2()
{
    return param;
}

int main()
{
    getparam_2().push_back(9);
    for (const auto& i : param)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

This will print "12345".

Answer (score 1):

> But what are their differences?

The outcome is identical, so there is no difference in that regard.

From perspective of the abstract machine, prior to C++17, both examples have one copy and the second example has a move from that copy. But the move can be optimised away, so there's still no practical difference necessarily. Since C++17, there is just one copy and no move in either case.

There is minor difference for the abstract machine in where that copy happens. In first example the copy is outside the function while in the second example the copy is inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

**Return by value**

Copy of that value is returned to the caller.

**Return by reference**

Reference to the variable is passed back to the caller. The caller can then use this reference to continue modifying the vector.

If you are using `int` in the vector you do not have to bother return by reference
it does not make big different. If you are using class or struct you should take consideration of using return by reference or pointer.